# Why do I lose the focus of the input when I write the first letter?

Tags: angular

I am working with angular reactive forms, I'd like to know why I lose focus when I write the first letter in the text entry. I want to write 'my user', but when I write the first letter 'm' I lose focus. Does anyone know why?

This is the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-oi7nkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPuv3.png)

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Shabu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're looping over form.controls.pasatiempos. **value** (BAD), not over form.controls.pasatiempos. **controls** (OK)

```
<div formArrayName="pasatiempos">
 <div *ngFor="let creds of form.controls.pasatiempos?.controls; let i = index">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular enumerates every action in your ng-container after you make some actions and executes it in a loop